# How to use Popen to open a program in Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on a Python project to open an application in Windows. The following program is written like so

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['open','C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe'])
```

Expected:
The calculator app should open.

Actual:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
PS C:\Users\EvanGertis\development\PythonAutomation\Module9>
```

Comment: `open` is not a standard Windows utility; were you trying to follow instructions for MacOS, where there is an `open` utility which (vaguely) makes sense to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `open` parameter argument from the function `Popen` works well in Python 3:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe'])
```

Also, you can use `call()` instead of `Popen()`, with the same result:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe'])
```

Comment: The result is not exactly the same. `Popen` creates a new subprocess and returns an object which represents the running process, while `call` waits for the process to finish, and returns its exit status (roughly equivalent to calling `communicate()` on the `Popen` object, and then retreiving its exit status).

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the information. I said `the same result` because in the question OP only wanted to open a program. But knowing what's happening in the background should be considered too.

Comment: Windows GUI programs are peculiar because they *appear* to exit immediately after starting the GUI. You would notice the difference much more if you ran a non-GUI program, or tried this on a non-Windows platform.